# Определить местоположение по gprs

Tags: gprs, android

Доброго времени суток. 
Собственно сам вопрос - как определить местоположение с помощью gprs ?

Answer (score 3):

Юзать [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

1) В манифесте пермишен:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

2) Создать менеджер:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

3) Реализовать `LocationListener`

```
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();  
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(  
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

4) Пример своего `LocationListener`

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        editLocation.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                    + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

В `onLocationChanged` получаете текущее положение

Answer (score 3):

Но лучше пользоваться новым методом работы с местоположением, подробно описано [здесь](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)
Данный метод меньше кушает батарейку и может получать координаты из разных источников(согласно докладку с Google IO).

Что из себя представляет "новый метод"? Это классы из Android Library(Google Play Services), которая лежит(если вы ее скачали и установили через SDK Manager) в /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject. С самим классом времени поковыряться нет, но я предполагаю, что это удобная и эффективная реализация, нежели свои велосипеды, обертки вокруг LocationManager-а.